# How to group and filter elements in list using groupby?

Tags: python, list, group-by

I have the following list:

`itemlist=[('ItemA', '0', 'Type1'), ('ItemA', '0', 'Type2'),('ItemA', '0', 'Type1'), ('ItemB', '0', 'Type2'), ('ItemA', '1', 'Type2'), ('ItemB', '2', 'Type1'), ('ItemB', '1', 'Type3'), ('ItemB', '1', 'Type1'), ('ItemC', '1', 'Type4'), ('ItemD', '1', 'Type4')]`

Next, i grouped items by number, and count numbers:

```
from itertools import groupby

sortkeyfn_num = key = lambda s:s[0]
itemlist.sort(key=sortkeyfn_num)

result_name_dict = {}
for key,valuesiter in groupby(itemlist, key=sortkeyfn_num):
    result_name_dict[key] = tuple(v[1] for v in valuesiter)

res = {}
for k in result_name_dict.keys():
for i in result_name_dict.values()[result_name_dict.keys().index(k)]:
    res.setdefault(i, 0)
    res[i] += 1
print k,'=', res
res.clear()
```

Result:

```
ItemB = {'1': 2, '0': 1, '2': 1}
ItemC = {'1': 1}
ItemA = {'1': 1, '0': 3}
ItemD = {'1': 1}
```

But how to group items by number and type, and count types in result?
Result must be, for example:

```
ItemA 0: Type1 = 2
ItemA 0: Type2 = 1
ItemA 1: Type2 = 1
ItemB 0: Type2 = 1
ItemB 1: Type3 = 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Here we go again.  Time 3 of closing this _exact_ same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724573/filter-items-by-groupby

Comment: If you would like our help, then you should respect the rules of this site and ask an [on-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Then, the coders here will be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: You need to show some effort to solve this problem yourself.  SO isn't a "code for me for free please" site.  We _assist_ you with _your_ coding.  We don't code for you.  In the link I gave, please read example 3 of a "still off-topic question".  Also, I want to say that there are no hard feelings here.  I, like the others who voted to close your questions, am only trying to keep SO clean.

Comment: Sorry. Here my code. Help me, if You can. Thanks.

Comment: So, i have another question. But 'Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account'. How can i ask? What i must do?

Comment: Eh, I can't really help you there.  You'd need to work with the SO moderators.  Here is a reference I found: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: Can somebody voted for '+' my question? I understood my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
import collections
itemlist = [('ItemA', '0', 'Type1'), ('ItemA', '0', 'Type2'),('ItemA', '0', 'Type1'), ('ItemB', '0', 'Type2'), ('ItemA', '1', 'Type2'), ('ItemB', '2', 'Type1'), ('ItemB', '1', 'Type3'), ('ItemB', '1', 'Type1'), ('ItemC', '1', 'Type4'), ('ItemD', '1', 'Type4')]
data_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 in itemlist:
    data_dict[(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3)] += 1
for key, value in sorted(data_dict.items()):
    attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 = key
    print("{attribute1} {attribute2}: {attribute3} = {value}".format(**locals()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here:

```
from collections import Counter
itemlist=[('ItemA', '0', 'Type1'), ('ItemA', '0', 'Type2'),('ItemA', '0', 'Type1'), ('ItemB', '0', 'Type2'), ('ItemA', '1', 'Type2'), ('ItemB', '2', 'Type1'), ('ItemB', '1', 'Type3'), ('ItemB', '1', 'Type1'), ('ItemC', '1', 'Type4'), ('ItemD', '1', 'Type4')]
for (a,b,c),d in sorted(Counter(itemlist).items()):
    print "{} {}: {} = {}".format(a, b, c, d)
```

Output:

```
ItemA 0: Type1 = 2
ItemA 0: Type2 = 1
ItemA 1: Type2 = 1
ItemB 0: Type2 = 1
ItemB 1: Type1 = 1
ItemB 1: Type3 = 1
ItemB 2: Type1 = 1
ItemC 1: Type4 = 1
ItemD 1: Type4 = 1
```